# Does facebook fql contain the sql like operator?

Tags: sql, facebook, facebook-fql

I am building a small facebook app. Trying to search for values in an auto compelte manner. Is it possible to use sql's like operator in fql?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### There is no LIKE operator in FQL.

However, you may have luck with the **IN** operator:

> WHERE "Stanford" IN
>   education_history.name

This page may also help and has sample queries:

- [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

Comment: Your two links are dead. The new documentation for FQL is at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Comment: This no longer works, see [alternative answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2642820/21115).

Answer (score 15):

Another way for you is to use the strpos(message, "content you want") >= 0. I don't know why, but the IN operator does not run for me. Did anyone try it?

Comment: +1. If you follow the FQL examples, they actually have some absolutely horrific examples using strpos.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is long since dead but I'm sure this may help someone in the future. FQL has its uses in some respects, but as far as searching for public information goes, I would recommend using the new graph api. I compared a simple FQL query with a similar graph query and on average, the graph was almost three times as fast (0.3s vs 0.8s). Here is a my graph example using PHP and CURL:

```
$search = "platform";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=".$search."&type=page");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$fbPages = json_decode($output)->data;
print_r(array_slice($fbPages, 0, 10));
```

Hope that helps!

PS: if you are not running PHP version 5.2.0 or above you will need a JSON decoder found [here](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198).

EDIT: you can find some useful documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

Comment: However, one of the disadvantages to using the Graph API `/search` endpoint instead of FQL is that you can only use it to search ***public posts***, while FQL allows you to search non-public posts, depending on what permissions you have with the user's access token: "We support search for the following types of objects...All public posts..." -- [Search documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/).