# FaceBook query using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

While fetching:
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=Select+page_id,page_url,name,pic,website,type,location,fan_count,phone+from+page+where+name%20%20=%22SPA%22
i am getting all exact match results with "SPA"
But how to get other which will match "sp" as well. Like when we use like operator in fql i am getting problem.
Please suggest me with solution

Answer (score 3):

here you go:

```
WHERE strpos(lower(name), 'sp') >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Hence there is no LIKE operator in FQL, you will have to use other alternative.
I hope this link will suggest you some way:

[Does facebook fql contain the sql like operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648285/does-facebook-fql-contain-the-sql-like-operator)