# Facebook FQL LIKE operator

Tags: sql, facebook, facebook-fql

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Does facebook fql contain the sql like operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648285/does-facebook-fql-contain-the-sql-like-operator)
>   [FaceBook query using FQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734550/facebook-query-using-fql)

Is it possible to use the familiar SQL LIKE operator within Facebook's query language?

I have tried running the query in the FQL test console, but it doesn't work. I'm wondering if I'm missing something or if it is simply not possible?

```
SELECT link_id from link WHERE url LIKE '%FRLJTjNC8So%' AND owner = '421235'
```

Go here to test:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/

Comment: similar, although this thread might be easier to reference given that the LIKE keyword is in the title.

Comment: Garcia That's the point of closing as duplicate - this reference will then point to the 'canonical' answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`SELECT link_id from link WHERE strpos(url,'FRLJTjNC8So') >=0 AND owner = '421235'`

There is no SQL `LIKE` in FQL. My solution uses FQL `STRPOS` instead. This works because it 
searches for the substring `FRLJTjNC8So` within the `URL` field.

The following thread was helpful

[Does facebook fql contain the sql like operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648285/does-facebook-fql-contain-the-sql-like-operator)

Comment: To do case-insensitive search, lower() method is available, and make sure that the second parameter (the search value or "FRLJTjNC8So" in the example above) is also using small letters. For example: [SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE uid=1207059 AND strpos(lower(message), "ben") >= 0] (https://developers.facebook.com/tool/explorer?fql=SELECT%20status_id%2C%20message%20FROM%20status%20WHERE%20uid%3D1207059%20AND%20strpos(lower(message)%2C%20%22ben%22)%20%3E%3D%200)