# it is possible to use the familiar SQL LIKE operator within Facebook's query language?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

it is possible to use the familiar SQL LIKE operator within Facebook's query language?

```
$fql = 'select fromid, text from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url LIKE "%youtube%") ORDER BY time DESC limit 5';
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648285/does-facebook-fql-contain-the-sql-like-operator

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation, there is no such feature: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/